# Why is Android Studio not opening for me?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have the JDK downloaded as well, and every forum I've seen this question  asked on says to add the variable JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME and I've tried both but it still doesn't open.

I've reinstalled Android Studio and restarted my computer but it isn't opening. I'm getting the loading icon like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wEDf.jpg) but it's just stuck on that.

I'm running Windows 8.1 and I have installed the most recent version of the JDK. Was really excited to start coding and any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: try to install 1.7 jdk version and try it.

Comment: Turn off Your Internet When first time you start Android Studio. As soon as you get the main screen of AS, You start the internet.

Comment: Enable virtualization technology at the BIOS Setup of your computer Because it is heavily needed for android studio as well as AVD manager,,,

Answer (score 1):

Though the question was raised long back but posting the answer to help someone stuck in the recent days,
as I was able to resolve the same issue by refer to the solution provided in Android Developer Portal,

[Studio doesn't start after upgrade](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#studio-config-directories)

If Studio doesn't start after an upgrade, the problem may be due to an invalid Android Studio configuration imported from a previous version of Android Studio or an incompatible plugin. As a workaround, try deleting (or renaming, for backup purposes) the directory below, depending on the Android Studio version and operating system, and start Android Studio again. This will reset Android Studio to its default state, with all third-party plugins removed.

For Android Studio 4.1 and later:

Windows: %APPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio Example: C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1

macOS: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio Example: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

Linux: ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio and ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio Example: ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1 and ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the android studio bundle version that has everything you want including the SDK. Set the environmental variable and you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd and type "java -version"
Make sure that you have java on your pc. If not, try to install it from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: This should be comment i think